# A post I made doesn't show any preview on edit and complains about "N.replace"

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown preview does not support link definition names that are the same as Array function names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/markdown-preview-does-not-support-link-definition-names-that-are-the-same-as-arra)

I had a problem creating [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872485/iterate-through-html-table-using-jquery-converting-the-data-in-the-table-into-js/2982285#2982285) on Stack Overflow; the preview stopped working at the end. And when I now edit it, the preview is blank. And before it complained about `N.replace`. It seems to be related to my use of dots in the label for links.

**Edit:**
My current browser is Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3

Comment: going to need more information than that...

Comment: Repro on Firefox 3.6.

Comment: I'm uncertain what information might be needed, though if you are able to edit others posts on SO, you can follow the above link and choose edit; you might see what I'm trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've got:

```
[map]: http://api.jquery.com/map/
[get]: http://api.jquery.com/get/
[text]: http://api.jquery.com/text/
```

as your URL links. Replace `map` with `1` in the body of your post and you'll see the post miraculously appear.

I've fixed up all three links now.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help seems to support the original syntax; or might it be only the preview that chokes? or might I've misunderstood the syntax?

Comment: @azatoth - I never spotted that on that page before. The links worked in the post so I guess it's just the preview that's broken.