# words contained in [] in questions and answers (not tags)

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown preview does not support link definition names that are the same as Array function names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/markdown-preview-does-not-support-link-definition-names-that-are-the-same-as-arra)

There seems to be something weird with the word "constructor" between brackets in the preview.

If you enter [constructor ] (without space) you cannot see anything else you type.

Are there anymore of these "keywords"? And why do they exist?

EDIT:
Test:
If I enter [constructor] and then text after I do not see anything after the "r" in the preview. However it might show up when I post?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Could you provide some details. Like browser/version, context when you try to type it (within a list or something like that).

Comment: Google Chrome (5.0.375.99), Windows Vista. Context, anywhere when I enter [constructor] in questions (as this one) or answers.

Comment: It posts fine however. It's just the preview before I post that messes up, and other words work perfectly fine. It seems to be limited to the word constructor

Comment: Aah, you meant the preview. Yes, I can reproduce it now. Chrome and Firefox. Nice catch.

Comment: Ladybug: added that to the question. and thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'll read up on the duplicate instead

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: Thanks for the improvements, but please note that editing a post bumps it to the front page. There's really no point in editing an ancient duplicate bug report just to fix a few trivial typos / spelling mistakes that don't hurt readability. Just let it languish in deserved obscurity.